# Sending and creating a File

Tags: java, file, sockets

I'm writing a custom protocol. I have a command name's put and the code looks as follows.

```
if(commandString.equals("PUT")){
    File f = new File(currentFolder, "test.txt");
    if(!f.exists())
         f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
    long size = 150;
    long count = 0;
    int bufferLeng = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    while((bufferLeng = dis.read(buffer))>0) //dis is a data input stream.
    {
        count =+ bufferLeng;
        fout.write(buffer);
    }
    System.out.println("All Good");
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

}
```

This command gets sent to the server by the client as follows `pWriter.println("PUT");`. Now I run this and it does create the file `test.txt` but then is freezes and the server does not display the All Good message. Why would this be and what is a easy fix?

The server and the client works!!

Thank you

Comment: `dis.read(buffer)` is a blocking call. Does your client close the connection?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that the code would even compile; look at the first line: `if(commandString.equels("PUT")){` Unless `commandString` is not `java.lang.String` (in which case your naming conventions appear inaccurate), the `equels(String)` method does not exist. Perhaps you meant `if(commandString.equals("PUT")){`

Comment: yes the client does close the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps eliminate `dis.read(buffer)` and use the following.

```
if(commandString.equals("PUT")){
    File f = new File(currentFolder, "test.txt");
    if(!f.exists())
         f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
    long size = 150;
    long count = 0;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int bufferLeng = buffer.length;
    while(count < size && bufferLeng>0) //dis is a data input stream.
    {

        fout.write(buffer);
        count =+ bufferLeng;
    }
    System.out.println("All Good");
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

}
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

The server waits for the client to close the socket. This would transmit the end-of-file which would cause `dis.read()` to return -1.

Usually, this isn't what you want. The solution is to send the file size before the data and then read exactly this amount of data.

Make sure your client calls `socket.flush()` after writing the last byte of file data or the data might get stuck in a buffer which would also cause the server to hang.

Comment: When I flush it after writing the last byte of the file it still hangs.

Comment: Make sure you don't read more bytes than the client sends. If you read even a single byte too many, it will hang. You will need to use the `read(buffer,offset,length)` method and calculate the length for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Also make sure you that you write only those bytes that `read()` has put into the buffer -> `write(buffer,offset,length)`